How to get all numeric values from this image?
The boxes in the image apparently cause trouble to Tesseract detection. Any tips how to configure Tesseract to extract all of the numbers from the image?

I always resize the image to make it 3x larger before feeding it to Tesseract.
I've already tried all possible --psm values. I've also tried limiting the charset to numbers only. No success at all. The output is either empty or full of non-sense.

Try deleting the boxes first. Make the flood fill black from point (0,0) and then fill white. Use ImageMagick.

Wow, that is a clever trick, Alex! Thank you, will try!

how are you using tesseract? in terminal or python?

In CMD/batch file.
